# Getting gradle context in a java program

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I have  a gradle build system and TestNg framework to run my tests. All test contains groups name. I want to fetch that groups name on runtime.
Is it possible to fetch the gradle context and from that is it possible to get the groups under which the corresponding test is running. For eg :

```
@Test(groups = {GROUP_A, GROUP_B, GROUPC})
public void test(){
/*Some code here that tells me under which group this test is running at run time*/
}
```

In above example, my gradle is setup so that it runs the test() for all GROUP_A, GROUP_B, GROUPC
. But is it possible somehow that I can know under which group is it running this test() at runtime. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You can't get this information from Gradle. If at all, you can get it from TestNG.

Comment: I would be really glad to know how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: If it's possible, you'll probably find it in the TestNG docs.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried TestNg docs. There are some interfaces (http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/ITestContext.html) which has some promising methods and implementation too (http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/TestRunner.html). But I am unable to use it as it is asking many values in Constructor which I don't know. IS there any better way? I am not sure if I am on the right path.

Comment: I don't know TestNG well enough to help with that.